# Scala / Play 2.5: Overloaded method apply with alternatives

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

I am using Scala & Play 2.5. I am stuck with this error:

```
Game.scala:99: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
[error]   (block: => play.api.mvc.Result)play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] <and>
[error]   (block: play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] => play.api.mvc.Result)play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] <and>
[error]   [A](bodyParser: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[A])(block: play.api.mvc.Request[A] => play.api.mvc.Result)play.api.mvc.Action[A]
[error]  cannot be applied to (Object)
[error]     def start(id: String, apiKey: Option[String]) = Action {
```

This is the function:

```
def start(id: String, apiKey: Option[String]) = Action {
  apiKey match {
    case Some(API_KEY) => {
      Server.actor ! Server.Start(id)
      Ok("Started")
    }
    case _ => Future.successful(Unauthorized)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, the result of the `match` statement has been inferred to be `Object`, since from one case statement you're returning `Result`, and from the other you're returning `Future[Result]`, so the only common super type is `Object`.  To fix, change `case _ => Future.successful(Unauthorized)` to `case _ => Unauthorized`.